# How can i save an iteration and use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

i want to save the iteration "grid" like this :

```
print(grid)
['*', '*', '*', '*']
['*', '*', '*', '*']
['*', '*', '*', '*']
['*', '*', '*', '*']
```

But in my code if i use print(grid) this appear

```
files = 4    
columns = 4    
grid = []

for i in range(files):
    grid.append([])
    for j in range(columns):
        grid[i].append("*")

for i in range(0, len(grid)):
    print(grid[i])

print(grid)
[['*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*', '*']]
```

How can i do it? Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'save' the grid in a different manner. You can print if differently though:

```py
for row in grid:
    print(row)
```

This way you loop over the grid list and print its elements 1 per line. The elements are in your case lists: `['*', '*', '*', '*']`.